# Zero "norm" properties

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, triangles

I have seen the claim that the l0-norm ($\|X\|_0$ = support(X)) is a pseudo-norm because it does not satisfy all properties of a norm. I thought it to be triangle inequality, but am not able to show it by example. Can anyone give an example to show that the l0-norm does not satisfy the triangle inequality?

Thanks.

Comment: It does not violate triangle inequality. It's not positive homogeneous.

Comment: This can't be the support of $X$. It must be its measure for some measure. The counting measure if $X$ is a finite-dimensional vector. The measure at use if $X$ is some measurable function.

Answer (score 9):

> is a semi-norm because it does not satisfy all properties of a norm.

This is a misuse of the term seminorm, which is [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) as a norm, except that it's okay for a nonzero element to have seminorm $0$.

The cardinality of support satisfies the triangle inequality, since the support of the sum of two vectors is contained in the union of their supports.

But the property $\|\lambda x\|=|\lambda|\|x\|$ clearly fails for $l_0$: instead we have $\|\lambda x\|_0=\|x\|_0$ for all $\lambda\ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps a better term is pseudo-norm? My memory was just clouded by glancing at semi-norm in some wiki articles without exactly reading through it.

Comment: @AtulDeshpande Pseudo-norm is better, although it's also sometimes used as a synonym of "seminorm". Then there's [quasinorm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasinorm) but it weakens the triangle inequality instead. I don't think there is a standard term for the concept obtained from *norm* by changing the homogeneity requirement.